# Swiping to close an external panel leaves the button highlighted. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile

I have the following overlay external panel:

```
        <div data-role="panel" id="panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
            <h1 style="background-image: url('img/image.jpeg');width:240px;height:60px;border-radius: 8px;">Options</h1>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="list-divider" style="font-style: italic;">File</li>
                <li><a href="#filepage">Load file</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This panel is activated from a href button in the header of every page and it can also be activated on a right swipe. To close the panel, the user can either click externally from the panel or swipe left. The problem is that when I click on the href button to open the panel and then swipe left to close it, the button remains in a activated highlightend state. It only gets back to its not-clicked state, when I tap on the page.

Here is the definition of the header, where the button for the panel resides:

```
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <a href="#panel" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>
                <h1>Home Page</h1>
                <a href="#infopage" data-icon="info">Info</a>
            </div>
```

I have tried multiple things including artificially clicking/tapping on a current page, playing with the button attributes, but no luck so far. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current focused button and remove the focused style `ui-focus`, like this:

```
$(element).removeClass($.mobile.focusClass);
```

or You can simply blur the active document element, whichever it is.

**DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#panel")
    .panel({
      theme: "a",
      display: "overlay",
      position: "right",
      positionFixed: false,
      dismissible: true
    })
    .enhanceWithin()
    .on("panelbeforeopen", function(e, ui) {
      $(document.activeElement).blur();
    });
  $(document).on("swipeleft", function(e) {
    $("#panel").panel("open");
  });
  $(document).on("swiperight", function(e) {
    $("#panel").panel("close");
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-page-active,
.ui-popup-screen,
.ui-popup-container,
.ui-panel-dismiss,
.ui-panel-display-overlay {
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="#panel" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <a href="#infopage" data-icon="info">Info</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="panel" id="panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
    <h1 style="background-color: grey; width:240px; height:60px ;border-radius: 8px;">Options</h1>
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li data-role="list-divider" style="font-style: italic;">File</li>
      <li><a href="#filepage">Load file</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

(As a bonus, i added the CSS fix for the Chrome warning: *Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive*)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! Unfortunately, both didn't work for me. I use the following code to be able to swipe open and close the panel :
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
    $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {
        if ($(".ui-page-active" ).jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
            if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
                $("#panel").panel("close");
            } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
                $("#panel").panel("open");
            }
        }
    });
});

Comment: You can omit your check for the panel status (open/closed), it is already built-in in JQM.